# Illuminate\Support\Manager::createDriver(), called in C:\xampp\htdocs\api\vendor\illuminate\support\Manager.php on line 87 and defined

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

**UserContorller.php**

```
public function mail(Request $request)
    {

        Mail::send('Email.test', ["customer" => "John Doe"], function ($message) {
            $message->to('abc@gmail.com', 'example_name')->subject('Welcome!');
        });

    }
```

**web.php**

```
$app->get('mail','UserController@mail');
```

**config/mail.php**

```
<?php

return [
    'driver' => "smtp",
    'host' => env('MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com'), // 根据你的邮件服务提供商来填
    'port' => "465", // 同上
    'encryption' => "ssl", // 同上 一般是tls或ssl
    'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
    'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
    'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME'),
    ],
];
```

`error in ErrorException in Manager.php line 77:`

Missing argument 1 for `Illuminate\Support\Manager::createDriver()`, called in `C:\xampp\htdocs\api\vendor\illuminate\support\Manager.php` on line 87 and defined in lumen api.

Comment: did you tried 'host' => env('MAIL_HOST') instead of 'host' => env('MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com') and add MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com to your .env file

Comment: Shouldn't `env('MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com')` be `env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.gmail.com')` ?

Comment: Here is the possible solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/51607539/4059179

Answer (score 0):

if the `.env` file is correct  I suggest removing the `composer.lock` file and remove the `vendor` directory and run the `composer install` again. Maybe the complete package is not installed.