# Laravel: Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Support\Manager::createDriver()

Tags: php, laravel

I try to test emails with mailtrap and Laravel 5.4. I get this error:

> Type error: Too few arguments to function
>   Illuminate\Support\Manager::createDriver(), 0 passed in
>   C:\Users***\Documents\www\***\backend\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Manager.php on line 88 and exactly 1 expected

I already tried to `config:cache`, `config:clear`etc.

Here is what `php artisan tinker`returns when I echo `env('MAIL_DRIVER')`

> smtp

Here is my .env file

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io 
MAIL_PORT=2525 
MAIL_USERNAME=*********
MAIL_PASSWORD=*********
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

And here is my Mail function:

```
Mail::send('email.verify', compact('validation_code'), function($message) {
    $message->to(Input::get('email'), Input::get('username'))
        ->subject('Verify your email address');
});
```

Any ideas ?

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: try `php artisan vendor:publish` ?

Comment: Are you using any cache system? Try to clear the bootstrap/cache folder

Comment: @Doddo Please follow this link (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29083520/attempting-to-get-email-to-work-in-laravel-5)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Attempting to get Email to work in Laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29083520/attempting-to-get-email-to-work-in-laravel-5)

Comment: @Rishi I tried, nothing changes :/

Comment: @Maraboc I already followed this thread

Comment: Any solution for this?

Comment: I think the problem was about publishing vendor or dumping .env file, can't remmember exactly, sorry :/

Answer (score 2):

Here is possible solution

Make sure followings are not empty

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this happens if you do not have the APP_KEY set in a .env file, so run `php artisan key:generate` if you do not have one.